# Gaussian elimination with $4x-3y=11$ and $x-3y=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gaussian-elimination

(Meta: What's the notation for showing two equations on two lines within a set of square braces []?)

Excuse syntax.

I would like to use Gaussian elimination to solve the system $[4x+3y=11]$ and $[x-3y=-1]$

I'm following the exercise 'Try it #3' on [this online text book page](https://openstax.org/books/college-algebra/pages/7-6-solving-systems-with-gaussian-elimination):
[image]

The solution provided is [over here](https://openstax.org/books/college-algebra/pages/chapter-7):
[image]

The solution is $(2, 1)$ whereas I got $(0, -3.67)$

Since I don't know the syntax for multiple rows within a square brace [] I'm going to screen shot my working:

[image]

ON the left column I work towards having all 1 in the diagonal and 0 underneath this diagonal line.

First I swap the rows.

Then I multiple new row 1 by -4 and add it to row 2 to delete the 4.

Then I divide row 2 by 12.

This gives me $y=-3.67$ and I use this on the right column to back substitute and solve to get the $(x,y)$ points.

I got $(0, -3.67)$ whereas the right answer is $(2,1)$. Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $(2,1)$?

Comment: You are making mistake. When you say, _I multiple new row 1 by -4 and add it to row 2 to delete the 4_ you are not doing it correct. Check your work where you multiplied row $1$ by $-4$ and added to row $2$. In any case, why did you not simply add row $1$ and $2$, that gives you $x$ straightaway.

Comment: Ah because $+3y$ and $-3y$? Yes that makes total sense now that you highlight it. I'm just learning this for the first time :)

Comment: that's alright but even what you did earlier should work but you did not add rows correctly. You wrote $44$ in second row whereas you were multiplying row $1$ by $-4$ and not row $2$.

Comment: Got it, I see it now. Thanks! MAybe I should delete?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would use that method for such a trivial problem.  Looking at "4x+ 3y= 11" and "x- 3y= -1" you should immediately see that "3y" and "-3y" cancel when you add them.  Adding the two equations, you get 5x= 10 so x= 2.  Then 4x+ 3y= 8+ 3y= 11, 3y= 3, y= 1.

Comment: @user247327 in my post I refer to a textbook. I'm working my way through a textbook to learn new concepts. After I learn and reinforce the new concepts I'll be better equipped to know when to use which method. Your comment reads as condescending and snobby. "... you should immediately see that.." Please forgive me for not being as advanced as math as you, after-all I am only learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use [*Gaussian Elimination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). Our augmented matrix is
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    4 & 3 & 11 \\
    1 & -3 & -1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
   1 & -3 & -1 \\    
   4 & 3 & 11 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - 4 R_1$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
   1 & -3 & -1 \\    
   0 & 15 & 15 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$R_2 \rightarrow R_2/15$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
   1 & -3 & -1 \\    
   0 & 1 & 1 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$R_1 \rightarrow R_1 + 3 R_2$

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
   1 & 0 & 2 \\    
   0 & 1 & 1 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Reading from the bottom row up, we have

$$y = 1, x = 2$$

Comment: The syntax - how do you markup square braces with multiple lines within them like that?

Comment: @DougFir: if you right click on top of any of them, and scroll to show math as Tex Commands, you can see the actual Mathjax. Regards.